# AngularJs: Using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) triggers unexpected http redirect from https

Tags: angularjs, location-provider, html5mode

I added the line

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

in app.js of my webapp in order to revove the '#' symbol from the URL. Once added this line (even only importing locationProvider) all requests in my site are redirected to http (port 80).

I need to use https, can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Laura

Answer (score 0):

Try and add  to the head.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
</html>
```

You might also want to look into
How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS Using .htaccess
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-using-htaccess/amp/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion but it did't work. However I already had a base href tag pointing to my App name. I replaced "/AppName/" with "/" but the https redirest happens anyway. I cannot workaround the issue using the .htacces file because in the release environment 80 port will be closed.